If I have a gen 5 Levono brand thinkpad that is stuck in bios loop, how do I wipe system to make reinstallment of updated software possible? any fixes
2024 thinkpad stuck in bios loop, hard drive is not locked, but it will not proceed to reboot to Windows it simply flashes screen to black then boot screen again.
.

What is "bios loop"? Can you access BIOS? Can you bot from USB?

I've accomplished to download new software and place it first in the boot order to reflash device...now how to start process
